# PySide GUI program is unable to call a module which uses open function

Tags: python, io, pyqt, pyside

There are three files. The first file is a text file. The second python file reads and prints the text file. The third file is my PySide GUI program, it can not be used within my GUI module. How can I solve this?
File1:text.txt
hello world

File2:pro.py

```
def hello(self):
    with open('text.txt', 'r') as tx:
        for line in tx:
            print line
```

File3:Gui program

```
def retranslateUi(self, active_learning):
    all.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("all", "All", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    self.all_button.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("all", "All", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

    pro()
```

Normally when pro is called, it works. When it is called from the GUI module, this error is shown:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'text.txt'

Comment: Is it because the directory your script is actually executing from is not the directory containing `pro.py` and `text.txt`? Print out `os.getcwd()` and check if that's the directory containing `text.txt`.

Comment: They are in the same working directory. In addition, when if I use clicked function for the button, it won't work as well

Comment: Are all 3 files in the same directory and are you executing the script from that directory?

Comment: If possible edit your question describing the directory structure of your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files were not in the same directory. It is corrected. Now the code works. Thanks Paul Rooney

Answer (score -1):

```
def hello(self):
    with open('text.txt', 'r') as tx:  # try the absolute path here, as python will search files under working directory if it is not an absolute path.
        for line in tx:
            print line
```

Comment: Thanks kolossus, the files are in the same directory